# ReactJS Call function inside a function error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a project in *ReactJS*.

In **onTaskHero** function I'am trying to call **setTheKick** function but it show me an **error**.

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setTheKick')**

This is because the function I want to call is inside the *Axios Service*?

What is the solution? Thank you very much!

```
import axiosHero from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import HeadHero from './headhero'; 

class CovidHero extends React.Component{

constructor( props ){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        requestOptions : {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics',
            headers:{
                "x-rapidapi-host":
                "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",
                "x-rapidapi-key":"b8b679d0d8msh05c65a5a3cfdb34p1337b3jsnc1c598d825a0"
            }
        }
    };

    this.onTaskHero = this.onTaskHero.bind(this);
    this.setTheKick = this.setTheKick.bind(this);

}

setTheKick(e, t, a, n) {
    let c = document.createElement("div");
    c.className += t;
    let d = document.createElement("span");
    d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a));
    c.appendChild(d);
    let i = document.createElement("span");
    i.appendChild(document.createTextNode(n));
    c.appendChild(i);
    e.appendChild(c);
}

onTaskHero( letter__init ) {

    axiosHero.request(this.state.requestOptions).then(function (e) {
        const datacenter = e.data.response;
        let home = document.getElementsByClassName("treeBody")[0];
        for( let databox in datacenter ){
            if( datacenter[databox].country.charAt(0) === letter__init ){
                
                home.innerHTML = '';

                let s = document.createElement("div");
                s.className += 'box';
                let r = document.createElement("h2");

                r.appendChild( document.createTextNode( datacenter[databox].country ) );
                s.appendChild(r);
                this.setTheKick(s, "total", "Total cases:", datacenter[databox].cases.total);
                this.setTheKick(s, "new", "New cases:", datacenter[databox].cases.new);
                this.setTheKick(s, "active", "Active cases:", datacenter[databox].cases.active);
                this.setTheKick(s, "critical", "Cases in danger:", datacenter[databox].cases.critical);
                this.setTheKick(s, "recovered", "Recovered:", datacenter[databox].cases.recovered);
                this.setTheKick(s, "deaths", "Deaths:", datacenter[databox].deaths.total);
                this.setTheKick(s, "newdeaths", "New deaths:", datacenter[databox].deaths.new);
                home.appendChild(s);         
            }
        }

    })

}

componentDidMount() {
    this.onTaskHero("A");
}

render(){

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <HeadHero head_2={"COVID"} head_3={"UNDER CONSTRUCTION"} />
            <div class="sorting">
            <ul>
                <li class="ltr gun" data-letter="A" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("A") }}>A</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="B" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("B") }}>B</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="C" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("C") }}>C</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="D" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("D") }}>D</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="E" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("E") }}>E</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="F" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("F") }}>F</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="G" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("G") }}>G</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="H" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("H") }}>H</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="I" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("I") }}>I</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="J" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("J") }}>J</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="K" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("K") }}>K</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="L" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("L") }}>L</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="M" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("M") }}>M</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="N" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("N") }}>N</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="O" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("O") }}>O</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="P" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("P") }}>P</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="Q" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("Q") }}>Q</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="R" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("R") }}>R</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="S" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("S") }}>S</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="T" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("T") }}>T</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="U" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("U") }}>U</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="V" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("V") }}>V</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="W" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("W") }}>W</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="X" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("X") }}>X</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="Y" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("Y") }}>Y</li>
                <li class="ltr" data-letter="Z" onClick={() => { this.onTaskHero("Z") }}>Z</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <div className="treeBody"></div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

}
export default CovidHero;

Comment: I think if you use a lambda instead of an anonymous function for the axios.then callback, the execution context will refer to the encapsulating environment, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a functional component to remove all the complexity of managing callback execution contexts. The refactor is really simple:

```
const requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics',
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host":
    "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "b8b679d0d8msh05c65a5a3cfdb34p1337b3jsnc1c598d825a0"
  }
};

const CovidHero = () => {
  const setTheKick = (e, t, a, n) => {
    // ...
  };

  const onTaskHero = (letter__init) => {
    axiosHero.request(requestOptions).then((e) => {
      // ...
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => onTaskHero("A"), []);

  return <>...</>;
};
```